# How to create totp verificator form to this serverjs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a task in JavaScript but I don`t know anything about it. I found a video which helped to solve my problem but now I must create a form which check all results. In postman I entered token and pass.

```
const express = require('express');
const speakeasy = require('speakeasy');
const QRCode = require('qrcode');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const cod = 123
const secret = speakeasy.generateSecret();
console.log(secret);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello');
})

app.get('/twofactorsetup', (req, res) => {
    QRCode.toDataURL(secret.otpauth_url, (err, data_url) => {
        res.send(
            `<h1>setup authenticator</h1>
      <img src=${data_url} > 
      <br>Manually: ${secret.base32}`
        );
    })
})

app.post('/verify', (req, res) => {
    token = req.body.userToken;
    const pass = req.body.pass;
    token = token - cod;
    console.log('first');
    console.log(token);
    token = token + pass
    console.log('sec');
    console.log(token);
    const verfied = speakeasy.totp.verify({ secret: secret.base32, encoding: 'base32', token: token });
    res.json({ success: verfied });
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started ISZZI');
});
```

What should I do? Any videos or tutorials
Thank you!

Comment: You should try to be more specific in what is failing for you exactly

Comment: I need to create a form and bind it to the server part. Must be authenticated with totp and another password.

Comment: I understand your high level requirement, but what did you get stuck with? Are you asking people to write code for you? What did you try?